# Mirth - iterate over insurance HL7 segments

Tags: mirth

working with an ADT message template in Mirth, having issues with the IN1 and IN2 segments, the IN2 specifically.
Here's a sample message that I'm working with, removed almost all the segments.
MSH|^~&|EPIC|AMB||99|20220403165344|RELEASEAUTO|ADT^A04|367476|T|2.5|||AL|NE
IN1|1|10500201|105^Test|BCBS NC BLUE CARE^Test1|PO BOX 35^^DURHAM^NC^27702^||
IN2|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||first iteration IN1-62||
IN1|1|10500201|106^Test|BCBS NC BLUE CARE^Test1|PO BOX 35^^DURHAM^NC^27702^||
IN2|||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||||second iteration IN1-62||

So far I've built the following to iterate over the IN1 segment:

```
//IN1 Segments
var IN1count=0;
for each (seg in msg.IN1) {
    createSegment('IN1',output,IN1count);
    output.IN1[IN1count]['IN1.2'] = seg['IN1.2'];
    output.IN1[IN1count]['IN1.3'] = seg['IN1.3'];
    output.IN1[IN1count]['IN1.4'] = seg['IN1.4'];
    output.IN1[IN1count]['IN1.8'] = seg['IN1.8'];
    output.IN1[IN1count]['IN1.9'] = seg['IN1.9'];
    output.IN1[IN1count]['IN1.10'] = seg['IN1.10'];
    output.IN1[IN1count]['IN1.12'] = seg['IN1.12'];
    output.IN1[IN1count]['IN1.13'] = seg['IN1.13'];
    output.IN1[IN1count]['IN1.22'] = seg['IN1.22'];
    output.IN1[IN1count]['IN1.36'] = seg['IN1.36'];
    IN1count++;
    }
```

I'm struggling to map the IN2 segment correctly on the outbound, I've read about getSegmentsAfter but I can't find that function online... how do I write the correct JS code to look for whether the given IN1 has an IN2 after, specifically if it has IN2-61, and only then create the IN2 segment?

Hope that makes sense :)

Comment: The `getSegmentsAfter` code template you were asking about is found here: https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect-examples/tree/master/Code%20Templates/Get%20Segments%20After%20a%20Particular%20Segment

Answer (score 1):

1. You'll find code for createSegmentAfter here; it is JavaScript inserted before your transformer: https://github.com/nextgenhealthcare/connect/blob/2f3740db44c8d42aa6fafffd991b9c1fde940ea0/server/src/com/mirth/connect/server/builders/JavaScriptBuilder.java
2. One approach to keeping track of whether you just passed an IN1 would be to loop over all segments with something like this:

   ```
    var was_in1 = false;
    var last_in1;
    for each ( seg in msg.children() ){
     if (was_in1) {
      if (seg.name() == "IN2") {
       // existing IN2 follows IN1
      } else {
       // insert new IN2
     }
     if (seg.name() == "IN1") {
       was_in1 = true;
       last_in1 = seg;
     } else {
       was_in1 = false;
     }
   ```

   }

Answer (score 1):

It'd be nice if there was a "nextSibling()" method for messages, but there isn't. Luckily, we can simulate it by:

1. Getting the current object's childIndex
2. Getting all children from the current object's parent
3. Access the next child with the index *childIndex + 1*

It'd look like this:

```
for each (seg in msg.IN1) {
    // Do your IN1 stuff ...

    var nextSeg = seg.parent().children()[ seg.childIndex() + 1];
    if(nextSeg != null && nextSeg.name() == 'IN2' && nextSeg['IN2-61'].toString() != '') {
        // Do yourIN2 stuff ...
    }
}
```